# Alternative to Jenkins X

Tags: open-source

We were using Jenkins X v2, for our CI & CD to leverage Gitops model. V2 has been deprecated and the V3 is not compatible to our on-prem k8's cluster that is behind the corporate proxy. I'm looking for an alternative for Jenkins X, that should be open source and supports CI as well, because ArgoCD & FluxCD are mainly CD oriented.